# Check whether array elements of array are present in another array in python

Tags: python

I have two arrays as:

`a = [[1,2,3,4],[3,1,2,4],[4,3,1,2],...]` and `b = [[4,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[3,2,4,1]....]`

I want to return a `True` for every row element of `a` if it is found in `b`. For the visible part of the above example the result should be c = [True, False, False]. Numpy solution is welcomed.

Comment: They are not arrays. They are lists.

Comment: @ DYZ my bad. C habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most naive solution:

```
[(x in b) for x in a]
#[True, False, False]
```

A more efficient solution (works much faster for large lists because sets have constant lookup time but lists have linear lookup time):

```
set_b = set(map(tuple, b)) # Convert b into a set of tuples
[(x in set_b) for x in map(tuple,a)]
#[True, False, False]
```

Comment: For the first solution, is it possible to return the index of `b` rather than `True` or `False`. Assume all elements could be found and you don't have address can't find anything behaviour.

Comment: Everything is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` for this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[3,1,2,4],[4,3,1,2]])
b = np.array([[4,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[3,2,4,1]])    
(a[:, None] == b).all(-1).any(-1)

out: array([ True, False, False])
```